# Up docker container with redis 2.8 on macOS M1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, apple-m1

Is it possible run docker container with `redis:2.8` on macOS with M1?
[docker log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fIp.png)

Setup:

- macOS M1
- docker-compose.yml with redis 2.8

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:2.8
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

- Install docker through official documentation https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/#mac-with-apple-silicon
- Run Docker application
- Go into Redis2.8
- Run container through button on top right corner
- I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fIp.png)

In another way through

```bash
docker-compose up redis
```

I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYXyO.png)

Comment: Yeah, it probably is. If you share some more information on what you have done to try and run it you may get more responses. At a minimum, share the command you are using to try and run the docker container and a full logging transcript from that command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnXF I improved me question

Comment: to reach the widest audience - specially on cross-platform tools like docker - try and stick to executing things via commands at a command prompt. For example, on my Windows machine if I create a ``compose.yml`` file containing the definition you have above then I can execute the command like ``docker-compose -f .\compose.yml up`` and redis starts up for me. If that works for you too then obviously 'run container through button on top right corner' is not quite the same thing.

Comment: @JohnXF I added result of `docker-compose up redis` to question description

Comment: If you google the error you are getting ``runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)`` you will see a hit on a stackoverflow question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349391/failed-to-create-new-os-thread-have-2-already-errno-22 - that looks to provide the answer. Your platform of your M1 mac is not compatible with that specific image you are using so you need to find an image that will work on your M1 Mac.

Comment: @JohnXF ok, I got it. Thank you for help. You can provide your comment as answer and I will accept it as right one if you wish

Comment: redis 2.8 is 9 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google the error you are getting at runtime ...

```
failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
```

you will see a hit on another StackOverflow question [Failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349391/failed-to-create-new-os-thread-have-2-already-errno-22). That looks to provide the answer - the platform of your M1 Mac is not compatible with that specific image you are using so you need to find an image that will work on your M1 Mac.